# How to use the Transform API provided by Android Gradle plugin？

Tags: android, gradle, transform, gradle-plugin

I used **applicationVariants.dex.dependsOn** task to do some extra work before codes were converted into dex file, and it worked all fine before android gradle plugin 1.3. But since 1.4, dex task was prohibited to access and would show such an error tip:
[image]

OK. I need to use the new **Transform API** instead of dex task. But the problem is there're really really few documents about the **Transform API**. What I could found is the Google official documents [here](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/javadoc/), but it seemed not very easy to understand.

So I tried to write a custom transform which I don't really know if I was right:

```
public class MyTransform extends Transform {

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "MyTransformImpl";
    }

    @Override
    public Set<QualifiedContent.ContentType> getInputTypes() {
        Set<QualifiedContent.ContentType> set = new HashSet<QualifiedContent.ContentType>();
        set.add(QualifiedContent.DefaultContentType.CLASSES);
        return set;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<QualifiedContent.Scope> getScopes() {
        Set<QualifiedContent.Scope> set = new HashSet<QualifiedContent.Scope>();
        set.add(QualifiedContent.Scope.PROJECT);
        return set;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isIncremental() {
        return false;
    }

}
```

It's an empty **custom Transform**. I haven't add the tranform logic, but that't not the problem.
Then I registered this **Transform** using the documented api in my gradle file:

```
def transform = new MyTransform()
project.android.registerTransform(transform)
```

Them when i execute assemble Task, my custom transform seems work. I can see it from the executing task list:

[image]

And finally the apk file was generated successfully, everything seems right. But when i install the apk and launch application, it crashed. With errors like this:

[image]

That's weird. Raised a **ClassNotFoundException**, and my **MainActivity** was missing. How it could be! Then I recompile my apk file and see the sources in the jd-gui, I was totally confused.

[image]

My codes are all missing. Only the classes in support library are remained. But actually my codes **.class** file are existed in the **app/build/intermediates/classes/** directory. And if I comment out the registration line in gradle:

```
// project.android.registerTransform(transform)
```

Everything goes right. So I guess I wrote a wrong **custom transform**, but I really don't know how to write a correct one.

Could anyone help? Thanks sincerely.

Comment: Hi Tony, could you please provide a sample app on GitHub for Transform API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you're implementing a `Transform` you have to process files and write them to an output folder. Even if you don't process class files you still have to copy them to the output folder. In case you don't do it all class files get removed.

To make the `Transform` work you have to perform the following steps. First, you need to specify that your transformation processes input class files and produces class files.

```
  @Override
  Set<QualifiedContent.ContentType> getInputTypes() {
    return Collections.singleton(QualifiedContent.DefaultContentType.CLASSES)
  }

  @Override
  Set<QualifiedContent.ContentType> getOutputTypes() {
    return EnumSet.of(QualifiedContent.DefaultContentType.CLASSES)
  }

  @Override
  Set<QualifiedContent.Scope> getScopes() {
    return EnumSet.of(QualifiedContent.Scope.PROJECT)
  }
```

Then in the `transform` method you need to get the input and the output folders.

```
final DirectoryInput directoryInput = inputs.first().directoryInputs.first()
final File input = directoryInput.file
final File output = outputProvider.getContentLocation(
    directoryInput.name, EnumSet.of(QualifiedContent.DefaultContentType.CLASSES),
    EnumSet.of(QualifiedContent.Scope.PROJECT), Format.DIRECTORY)
```

And finally you have to copy all files from `input` to `output`.

Here's a [project](https://github.com/MichaelRocks/lightsaber/blob/develop/gradle-plugin/src/main/groovy/io/michaelrocks/lightsaber/plugin/LightsaberTransform.groovy) that implements a `Transformation`. Maybe it will be easier for you to understand how transformations work with a real example.

Comment: Anything more specific? I really don't know how to process files and copy them to an output folder. Found nothing about this on the document. Thanks

Comment: Also I added a link to a project that uses Transform API.

Comment: Sorry I met another problem. In the transform method I can get the app module path by directoryInput.file and process my transform logic. But my project has some library modules in the same project. How do I transform these library codes as well? I tried every available scope in the document. But none of them seemed work. Thanks again for reply.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to do that. Anyway you should create another question.

Comment: Hi Michael, I am trying to implement Transform API by looking at the Git project. My android app is using Java only and your project contains groovy and kotlin which is making the concept little bit complex. could you please help provide a simpler version of the project?

Comment: @Krrishnaaaa As for the `Transform` part of the project, you can simply rewrite the `Transform` subclass in Java. It should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I have tried that part but still getting Dex task is not available in 1.4.1. I will try to push my code then will ask again. Meanwhile if you can guess the problem then provide the solution. 

Comment: You shouldn't use the `Dex` task directly.

Comment: Link is broken, project no longer exists